# Filtering Multi Value Taxonomy Managed Property against a Multi Value Query String Variable

Tags: search, search-results, sharepoint-search

When I use below line it works:

```
{|MultiValuedTaxManagedProperty:{Page.MultiValueTaxField}}
```

However I would like to do the same with a query string parameter:
**URL?Param1=Value1;Value2;Value3**

```
{|MultiValuedTaxManagedProperty:{QueryString.Param1}}
```

Am I using wrong format for Param1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up rebuilding the query string by using "k" variable.
Example:

https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/mySite/myPage.aspx?k=(MultiValuedTaxManagedProperty:value1 OR MultiValuedTaxManagedProperty:value1 OR MultiValuedTaxManagedProperty:value1)